# Create Azure Budget Alert through terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to replicate the process of creating an Azure budget alert in the portal through terraform.

In the portal, I navigate to Cost Management + Billing, then onto cost alerts and I'm able to create a alert with my conditions for the entire subscription for the budget not to exceed a certain amount otherwise to send an email to a specific group or person.

I'm able to create an action group in terraform through azurerm_monitor_action_group but how do I create an alert for the budget. I don't see any valid documentations for it.

Answer (score 3):

I found this provider that can be leveraged into terraform to create budget alert for the time being. Hope this helps anyone looking

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/innovationnorway/azure-preview/latest/docs/resources/azurepreview_budget

Answer (score 2):

As of March 16, 2021 it is still WIP, but the feature is coming.

You can track the progress here:

- https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/2677
- https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/9201

Answer (score 2):

There are official resources now: [`azurerm_consumption_budget_resource_group`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/consumption_budget_resource_group), [`azurerm_consumption_budget_management_group`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/consumption_budget_management_group) and [`azurerm_consumption_budget_subscription`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/consumption_budget_subscription)